# Печать Яндекс карты через JS

Tags: javascript, css, яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Имеется страница с Яндекс картой, у которой заданы ширина и высота для удобства просмотра на экране. Пользователю необходимо распечатать всю страницу с измененной высотой карты так, чтобы все красиво без сжатия масштаба помещалось на книжный лист А4. Для решения данной задачи пытаюсь использовать javascript и css-стили:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeprint', (event) => {               
    $('#map').addClass('bigMap');
    myMap.container.fitToViewport()
});
window.addEventListener('afterprint', (event) => {                
    $('#map').removeClass('bigMap');
    myMap.container.fitToViewport();                
});

#map {
    width: 1100px;
    height: 750px;            
}        
.bigMap {            
    height: 1400px !important;
}
```

Проблема состоит в том, что при таком способе размер карты меняется очень быстро и на печать выходит непрогруженная или частично прогруженная карта. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как дождаться перед печатью полной загрузки карты или другой способ реализации данной задачи, чтобы избежать описанной проблемы.

Comment: Наверное можно как-то задействовать [`@media print {  }`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/@media) вместо js для настройки печатного лейаута?

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Попробовал - с обычными элементами работает, а с картой нет

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте отслеживать окончание момента загрузки карты через [tileloadchange](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ILayer.html#event_detail__event-tileloadchange) для слоя подложки.